# Add space before a substring in a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = ["TP", "MP"]

list_2 = ["This is ABC12378TP0892S3", "This is XYZ12378MP0892S3"]
```

I want take elements from `list_1` and search in strings of `list_2`. If found (for example `TP` is present in `list_2`'s first string, `MP` is present in `list_2`'s second string), remove what is to the right of `TP, MP` etc. and insert space to left of it.

I tried the below with `re`, but it is removing only the right part:

```
[ re.sub(r'(' +  '|'.join(list_1) + ')\d+', r'\1', string) for string in list_2 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile a regular expression as follows, and then use it to do a `sub()` on each list entry:

```
import re

list_1 = ["TP", "MP"]
list_2 = ["This is ABC12378TP0892S3", "This is XYZ12378MP0892S3", "SDTP This is ABC12378TP0892S3"]    

re_sub = re.compile(r'(.*\b\w+)({}).*'.format('|'.join(list_1))).sub
list_2 = [re_sub(r'\1 \2', t) for t in list_2]

print list_2
```

This would display:

```
['This is ABC12378 TP', 'This is XYZ12378 MP', 'SDTP This is ABC12378 TP']
```

In this example, the search pattern being used is:

```
(.*\b\w+)(TP|MP).*
```

Comment: Could please explain this [re_sub(r'\1 \2', t) for t in list_2]. How exactly it is working?

Comment: The search pattern has two sets of `(....)`. When using `sub()`, the `\1` means to substitute the current location with the contents of the first `()`, and `\2`, the contents of the second `()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close. Add the space... `r' \1'`

Not sure about `\d+`, either, so replace that with `.*`

```
>>> [ re.sub(r'(' +  '|'.join(list_1) + ').*', r' \1', string) for string in list_2 ]
['This is ABC12378 TP', 'This is XYZ12378 MP']
```

Comment: @cricket-007 What if I have two substrings and I only want to insert space in one.Example list_1 = ["TP", "MP"]

list_2 = ["SDTP This is ABC12378TP0892S3", "This is XYZ12378MP0892S3"] and I don"t want to insert space for SDTP.

Comment: If that was your question, then you should have asked that from the start... You can't do the list comprehension, then, because you would need `' \2'` instead of `' \1'`

Comment: @cricket-007 SDTP can occur anywhere in the string. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Sure, but for the regex replacement, order matters... "SD**TP** This is ABC12378**TP**", there are two. If you want the space on the "ABC12378TP" part, then you have to do more work (or it just isn't possible)

Comment: @cricket-007 Is there anyway to use Quantifiers for this? Or if it is fixed SDTP occurs as first position in the string then?

Comment: I'm not skilled in regex, so I don't know what you are asking